# How to set CodeCommit repo branch name in CodeBuild project, during CI

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

CodeCommit repo is used as source for CodeBuild project, but I wanted a specific branch(eg: test) to be build on, rather than a default branch(eg: dev).
I tried setting up build commands as following but still takes default branch:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
  CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION: "test"

phases:
  build:
    commands:
     - echo Build started on `date`
 post_build:
    commands:
     - echo Build completed on `date`
     - echo This is the BranchName $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION
     - mvn clean -f ProjectName/pom.xml package
artifacts:
  files:
     - ProjectName/target/project.war
discard-paths: yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to [set sourceVersion in StartBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_StartBuild.html#CodeBuild-StartBuild-request-sourceVersion) to select the desired branch.

Comment: Thank you! Could you be more specific please. I can select the "Branch" while i am manually building through console. But, if i have to set this branch as default when triggering with CloudWatch, how can I do that ?
Also, even on the CLI i did not find any parameter for specifying branch name.

Comment: For CLI, I looked into the skeleton but, no sourceVersion parameter is present. You meant to put "version" parameter under "source"?  [CodeBuild-Skeleton](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/create-project.html#create-project-cli)
Also, I did not find any "settings" option in CodeBuild console. Could you please direct me, that will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: @usernamehidden You'll need to set the branch name in StartBuild, under source version.

Answer (score 2):

As Unsigned said, you need to set sourceVersion in StartBuild. If you plan on using CloudWatch Triggers to build based on commit branch, it defaults to using master branch. To change which branch to deploy based on commit see below.

Under the Targets:

1. Configure input
2. Constant (JSON text)
3. {"sourceVersion": "your-branch-to-build"}

[Image of Target Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqpuj.png)